# How can I do this with MySQL partitions

Tags: mysql, partitioning

I have a table with millions of rows and I want to create some partions, but I really don't know how I can to this. I mean I want to have the data which is starting with the ID 1 -> 10000 to be on partition one, and and the data that is starting with the ID 10001 -> 20000 to be on partition two; and so on...?Can you give me an example how to do it?

I have searched a lot on the internet and I read a lot of documentation, but I still don't understand how it needs to be done!

Best Regards,

Comment: Could you explain what exactly is not clear in http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/partitioning-range.html ?

Comment: Well there it shows that I have to create a table in order to do that, but I have the table already...with the data in it

Comment: Someone less lazy could click a couple of links and find **another** manual page: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/partitioning-management-range-list.html :)

Comment: @Alexander Konstantinov and how can I select the data, i.e from 1->1000 to create a partition and from 10001 to 20000? 
ALTER TABLE `dadsa` ADD PARTITION (PARTITION dadsa2 ?what comes here?));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you might start using partitions:

```
ALTER TABLE table_with_millions_of_rows
PARTITION BY RANGE (id) (
    PARTITION p0 VALUES LESS THAN (10000),
    PARTITION p1 VALUES LESS THAN (20000),
    PARTITION p2 VALUES LESS THAN MAXVALUE
)
```

Further information on how to manage (create, delete, change settings etc.) partitions can be found in MySQL manual's "[Partitioning](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/partitioning.html)" chapter.

*Note: partitioning in MySQL is available as of version 5.1.*

Comment: I'm getting this error
  #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'PARTITION BY RANGE (id) ( PARTITION p0 VALUES LESS THAN (10000), PARTI' at line 2

Comment: @Uffo, which MySQL version are you using?

Comment: Server version: 5.0.90-community-log
# MySQL client version: 4.1.22

Comment: @Uffo, Partitioning is available only since MySQL 5.1, you have to upgrade MySQL in order to use it.

Comment: @ Alexander Konstantinov Now i'm getting this when I try to partitionate, the engine is MyISAM; and I've also upgraded mysql to 5.1   #1214 - The used table type doesn't support FULLTEXT indexes

Comment: @Uffo, Everything is in the manual. **Everything**. :) http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/partitioning-limitations.html - _"Partitioned tables do not support FULLTEXT indexes. This includes partitioned tables employing the MyISAM  storage engine."_

Comment: Partitioning still doesn't solve my problem, the querys are taking aprox the same time..

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE part1 (...)
CREATE TABLE part2 (...)
INSERT INTO part1 SELECT * FROM original WHERE id => 0 AND id < 10000
INSERT INTO part2 SELECT * FROM original WHERE id => 10000 AND id < 20000
```

Comment: huh? thats not pruning...thats just spliting things up...I need to do that with Mysql partition...